# where pyi files are implemented (about .pyi files of socket listen() function)?

Tags: python, sockets, pyi

I wondered how `listen()` are implemented in the `socket` interface, so I clicked it on the vscode but only `.pyi` files are shown to me.

[image]

[image]

I searched about what is .pyi files and it says it is a interface file (like header file in C).
So where can I find the implementation of `listen()`?

Comment: That's complicated because a lot of Python function implementations are actually written in C and compiled. [Here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/929cc4e4a0999b777e1aa94f9c007db720e67f43/Modules/socketmodule.c#L3615) is what I believe the definition of `listen` is.

Comment: Confirming @Carcigenicate's link.